# Associate each elements of a numeric vector to the "most similar" level of a factor vector

Tags: r, vector, match

I have a numeric vector:

```
x <-c(-18.695, -18.695, 19.477, 0.000, 55.000, 19.477, -18.695, 48.476, 55.000, 37.798, -18.695, 19.477, 37.798, 0.000, -18.695)
```

and a factor vector, whose levels, as returned from the `levels` function, are:

```
y <- c("IV-18_7", "IV00", "IV00orig", "IV19_5", "IV37_8", "IV37_8_yp", "IV48_5", "IV48_5_yp", "IV55")
```

I need to build a new factor vector `z`, of the same length as `x`, but having the levels listed in `y`, and such that the i-th element of `z`, `z[i]` is the "most similar" element of `y` to the corresponding element of `x`, `x[i]`. In other words:

```
z <-factor(c("IV-18_7", "IV-18_7", "IV19_5", "IV00", "IV55", "IV19_5", "IV-18_7", "IV48_5", "IV55", "IV37_8", "IV-18_7", "IV19_5", "IV37_8", "IV00", "IV-18_7"), levels = y)
```

The example should make the meaning of "most similar" fairly obvious, anyway the idea is to take an element `x[i]` and then look for the element of `y` which is obtained by adding a "IV" prefix,  then adding a string which is "similar" to the roundoff of `x[i]` (but not exactly equal, unfortunately), and finally without any suffix after the numeric part. I don't know how to code this efficiently in R, can you help me?

Comment: This will get you pretty close for your example: `paste0("IV", gsub(".", "_", gsub("\\.0$", "", sprintf("%04.1f", round(x, 1))), fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: it seems not only pretty close but right on the spot! Thanks! Why don't you write it as an answer and explain what the single pieces do? It's difficult (for me) to understand one-liners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner that should get you pretty close.

```
paste0("IV", sub(".", "_", sub("\\.0$", "", sprintf("%04.1f", round(x, 1))), fixed=TRUE))

[1] "IV18_7"  "IV-18_7" "IV19_5"  "IV00"    "IV55"    "IV19_5"  "IV-18_7" "IV48_5"  "IV55" 
[10] "IV37_8"  "IV-18_7" "IV19_5"  "IV37_8"  "IV00"    "IV-18_7"
```

It works as follows. The original vector, x is rounded to the first significant digit. Then `sprintf` with the formatting "%04.1f" pads the result with a leading "0" if the number of characters is less than 4. This result is fed to `sub` which drops any instances of dots (periods) followed by "0". Finally, the outer `sub` replaces the dot with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, I first make a guess of the right format in x2 and then use edit distance to find the closest match

```
x <-c(18.695, -18.695, 19.477, 0.000, 55.000, 19.477, -18.695, 48.476, 55.000, 37.798, -18.695, 19.477, 37.798, 0.000, -18.695)
y <- c("IV-18_7", "IV00", "IV00orig", "IV19_5", "IV37_8", "IV37_8_yp", "IV48_5", "IV48_5_yp", "IV55")

x2 <- rep('', length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  x2[i] <- paste0('IV', floor(x[i]), '_', 10 * round(x[i] - floor(x[i]), 1))
}

# define edit distance and find the closest match
dist <- adist(x2, y)
z <- rep('', length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  m <- min(dist[i, ])
  w <- which(dist[i, ] == m)
  z[i] <- y[w]
}
```

Comment: it works! I didn't know about `adist`. In my environment the code runs with some warnings (`In z[i] <- y[w] :  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`) but other than that, it delivers the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that matching the integer part of `x` (disregarding sign) to the first two digits in `y` will suffice here, we can use `sub` to extract the first two digits from `y` and `match` `floor(abs(x))` to it as numeric:

```
x.int <- floor(abs(x))
y.2digits <- as.numeric(sub('.*?([0-9]{2}).*', '\\1', y))
z <- factor(y[match(x.int,y.2digits)],levels=y)
## [1] IV-18_7 IV-18_7 IV19_5  IV00    IV55    IV19_5  IV-18_7 IV48_5  IV55    IV37_8  IV-18_7
##[12] IV19_5  IV37_8  IV00    IV-18_7
##Levels: IV-18_7 IV00 IV00orig IV19_5 IV37_8 IV37_8_yp IV48_5 IV48_5_yp IV55
```